# How to write a app to log in with google domain email account

Tags: oauth, gmail

The scene is like this:there is a log in entrance,the users can use google app domain email to log in. How to write these codes?I know may need OAUTH to attrieve that,but do I need to get a google apps administrator account to do that,or just get the developer account to do this? sry my bad english, hope some1 could help me~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Any Google individual (eg gmail) or Apps user will be able to authenticate using this -- whether an admin or a regular user.

Your developer account can be any type of account (individual, Google Apps admin, Google Apps regular user).